# Don't we have any java built in method to find average of an array of Numbers?

Tags: java, arrays

I am checking and wondering there should be a method in java API to find average of an array of decimals. But not able to find it. Can you provide inputs if we have one and if not I wonder why, as this is very trivial method.

Answer:

For Arrays:

```
OptionalDouble averageOptional = Arrays.stream(new double[]{1, 2, 3}).average();
```

For List:

```
OptionalDouble averageOptional= list.stream().mapToDouble(val->val).average();
```

To find double value:

```
averageOptional.orElse(0D);

averageOptional.getAsDouble();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `stream` for this, in Java 8:

```
OptionalDouble average = Arrays.stream(new double[]{1, 2, 3}).average();
```

There's another interesting method:

```
Arrays.stream(new double[]{1, 2, 3}).summaryStatistics();
```

It returns a variable of type `DoubleSummaryStatistics`. It has data like `getMax()`, `getAverage()`, `getSum()`, etc.

Comment: Thanks! Do we have for ArrayList<Double> in particular, as well?

Comment: Of course, ArrayList has  ``.stream()`` method, that is what you need ;)

Comment: I got the required answer, thanks for the hints.
OptionalDouble average = list.stream().mapToDouble(val->val).average();

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.stream(new int[] {1,2,3}).average().get();`

Answer (score 1):

There's one in Java 8

```
double average = Arrays.stream(new double[]{1,2,5,8}).average().getAsDouble();
```